# Which is the best OS for WSS 3.0

Tags: wss-3.0

Hi
Which Server OS I should go for ? 2003 or 2008? for WSS 3.0

I will be migrating to MOSS 2007 in December

thx
-saumil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I always say go with the most current offering (2008), otherwise you're just going to end up multiple generations behind.

The next question, is that if 2008 is an option, why are you building a new environment with WSS3? Have you considered 2010/Foundations instead?

Comment: I will be migrating to MOSS 2007 in December until till then I will have to use WSS 3.0. Is 2008 good enough for MOSS 2007 or MOSS 2010??

Comment: Is there any reason you are migrating to MOSS instead of going to SharePoint 2010 Foundation? If you are running Windows Server 2008 with WSS3 then you'd save far more on licensing costs by migrating straight to SPF2010.

Comment: We have a license for MOSS 2007.

Comment: @saumil - Just to be clear.  In addition to the server license, MOSS requires user or device CALs for every user who accesses the site.  I believe that was the nature of James' question above.  I would definitely not discourage anyone from moving to MOSS as there are many more out of the box features, but wanted to be sure you were aware of the user licenses, too.

Comment: Yeah, User license issue has been taken care of. Thx for detials Rob!

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to run WSS under both Win 2003 and Win 2008. Frankly speaking, running WSS on Win 2003 has less issues than in Win 2008, but as what webdes mentioned, if you run your WSS on Win 2003, you will be several "generations" behind.

The most common issue I had on Win 2008 is about the user permission. Quite often, I had the permission issues on the _layouts folder (in which this is not the issue on Win 2003 at all)

Hope this helps

Comment: Good thing to point out and remember about Windows Server 2008, that it may seem to have these "Issues" like those mentioned here, but in actual fact they are security features which patch holes that existed in Server 2003 - much like the Loopback Checking feature in server 2003 - people disabled it as it seemed like it was causing an issue but in reality it was there for a reason.